# ArcGIS10: Publishing GPtools etc. in AddIns

Tags: arcgis-10.0, c#, .net

I'm creating an ArcGIS 10 add-in in .NET C# which contains some tool commands and an extension class.  This extension is being launched on application start-up.

If I create any custom GP Tools, custom symbology renderers, custom toolboxes etc. in code do these still need to be registered during an install or can I launch them (as in have a custom symbology class in a layer properties dialog) dynamically from the extension class during run time?

Assume that the user of the tools does not have admin rights to their machine.

Hopefully I've made myself clear if not just ask!

Thanks
Rob

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Feature renderer (their property pages) and GP tool factories need to be registered in their appropriate COM categories. That said, they cannot be distributed merely as addins but have to be part of some kind of installation procedure.

Comment: Thanks - I've just found the help page which confirms this:
http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Custom_geoprocessing_function_tools/000100000mrs000000/
Shame we can't add GP tools as part of the add-ins yet